# Query Staged files in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am interested in doing a bulk load to add loaded file name to a column in the target column. The file name contains the timestamp of the file created which helps us to identify the insert timestamp as a column.

I know I can do something like

```
COPY INTO MYTABLE(FILENAME,FILE_ROW_NUMBER,COL1,COL2) 
FROM (SELECT METADATA$FILENAME,METADTA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER,T.$1,T.$2 
        FROM @MYSTAGE(FILE_FORMAT => MYFORMAT)T) ;
```

But this works for a single file. All the files do not follow the same pattern and hence I cannot use `pattern` option. I am looking for something similar like `copy into` where I can specify `files`

One option is to filter files but that does not seem like very efficient if I have many files. Looking for options and suggestions.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by `But this works for a single file.`. When you specify `metadata$filename` for a row, it will put the name of the file that row came from. It will work for as many files as there are rows in the query. You can see this by running `select distinct METADATA$FILENAME from @MY_STAGE;` Can you elaborate on this point?

Comment: Could it be that you could use the optional parameter FILES for COPY INTO to specify a list of one or more file names (separated by commas) to be loaded? See the doc for reference and an example below: [doc reference](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#optional-parameters)


`copy into load1 from @stage
    files=('test1.csv', 'test2.csv')
    force=true;`